# Why are assigned licenses missing from the licenseAssignmentStates collection using Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

A user in my Azure AD has two license assignments, one direct and one via a group:

[image: Azure AD screenshot]

When querying the user, one of the licenses is missing from the licenseAssignmentStates collection. The property assignedLicenses contains the other license.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[UPN]?$select=licenseAssignmentStates,assignedLicenses

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(licenseAssignmentStates,assignedLicenses)/$entity",
    "licenseAssignmentStates": [
        {
            "skuId": "18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e",
            "disabledPlans": [],
            "assignedByGroup": "19f1820f-21d0-4d68-8c51-678a752168bc",
            "state": "Error",
            "error": "MutuallyExclusiveViolation"
        }
    ],
    "assignedLicenses": [
        {
            "disabledPlans": [
                "aebd3021-9f8f-4bf8-bbe3-0ed2f4f047a1",
                "8c7d2df8-86f0-4902-b2ed-a0458298f3b3",
                "57ff2da0-773e-42df-b2af-ffb7a2317929",
                "a23b959c-7ce8-4e57-9140-b90eb88a9e97",
                "e95bec33-7c88-4a70-8e19-b10bd9d0c014",
                "5dbe027f-2339-4123-9542-606e4d348a72"
            ],
            "skuId": "6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a huge problem, because if a license is not contained in the licenseAssignmentStates collection, it is impossible to know anything about the state of the license assignment or if it has been assigned by a group.

Before adding the indirect license assignment, the direct license assignment was returned in the licenseAssignmentStates collection, so I don't think it is about that.

How do I get the licenseAssignmentStates of all assigned licenses? Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in the Graph API? If it is, what would be the best way to get it fixed quickly, we need this for our application?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has logged it as a bug and it is in the queue for resolution: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9636#issuecomment-754933971

Answer (score 1):

I reproduce the error that you faced.

Step1: Add the license(Microsoft 365 Bussiness Standard) to user

Step2: Add the license(Microsoft 365 E3) to group

Step3: Add user as a member of this group

Then, I get the 2 licenses, one is direct(Active) and another is via group(error: Conflicting service plans). When I request the MS Graph API to get licenseAssignmentStates and assignedLicenses, I just find the error one.

[image]

[image]

Step4: Remove license(Microsoft 365 E3) from group license, API responses the direct(Active) one.

Step5: Add license(Dynamics 365 Plan) to group

I get following 2 licenses, both are Active. API responses them correctly.

[image]

[image]

I add the license(Microsoft 365 E3) to group again. API responses result correctly that contains the error one and others.

[image]

[image]

So, it seems BUG that licenses miss from the licenseAssignmentStates collection. You could remove the license which is an error to resolve it.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming my problem! I hope someone responsible from Microsoft reads it :-).

Comment: Hi, @ManuelK. You could feedback to [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory). If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to reserve judgment on that for now. It's obviously a bug, so in that sense it was not extremly helpful, because it did not fix my problem, even though you confirmed it as well. Although it was helpful to add information about how to reproduce it. But maybe someone comes along with a different solution or a Microsoft employee fixes the bug, that would be my preferred answer ;-).

Comment: @ManuelK As matters stand, the error will not occur if API responses correctly once. So you could remove the license which is an error first, then add it, you will get the result that you want.

Comment: This is not true for my case. I only had the direct license assignment at first and it was returned correctly. After adding the second indirect license with errors, only that one was returned. Also, in my use case I can't just go around changing customer's license assignments...

Comment: @ManuelK Inherited Office 365 Enterprise E1 license conflicts with E3 license which results in 'Conflicting service plans'. This should be corrected in Azure Active Directory > Groups> License ( Please refer to this article -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-groups-assign#step-3-check-for-license-problems-and-resolve-them )

Comment: In regards to the licenseAssignmentStates issue, we have passed your feedback along to the product team.

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity Thank you very much for your answer. I know why the licenses conflict and it does not matter to me. I just need correct output from the Graph API :-). I hope the bug is fixed quickly. Is there any way I can track the progress or be notified of the status?